# string output to html formatting problem

Tags: c#, html, string

I have the following string variables:

```
 string feedImage ="http://im.media.ft.com/m/img/rss/RSS_Default_Image.gif"

rssImageStyle = "style=\"background-image:url(\'" + feedImage + "\')\"";
```

I want it to output the following html

```
background-image: url('http://im.media.ft.com/m/img/rss/RSS_Default_Image.gif');
```

But I get

```
background-image: url(http://im.media.ft.com/m/img/rss/RSS_Default_Image.gif);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't escape ':

```
string feedImage ="http://im.media.ft.com/m/img/rss/RSS_Default_Image.gif"
rssImageStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('" + feedImage + "')\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't esacpe the single quotes.

i.e \' should be '

Answer (score 0):

You escaped ' and there is no need to do that. Try this: `rssImageStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('" + feedImage + "')\"";`